# How to download a file from db ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

Help me please. In my database there are files (for each page there is a file: dish recipe). Tell me how can download the file from the  html page. Files can be of different types. I would be very grateful if you would show some code examples.

Comment: What do you mean by "download", specifically? Do you mean to just render the file's text content in a page, or are you asking about using `Content-Disposition` to force the user's browser to prompt to save the page/resource to disk?

Comment: the ideal option is to allow the user to view the contents of the file and save it on a personal computer. These actions can be linked to different buttons. but it will be enough to save the file to disk